# AWS-CDK get secondary indexes and metrics for those

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I have a cdk stack with a DDB table created with some alarms over it. Now have successfully add a secondary index to it.

However, how can I programmatically list the secondary indexes that a table has and how can I get the metrics for it.

Background, we have a module which creates the alarms for our DDB tables. That module receives the cdk table object and creates some alarms over it using methods like `metricConsumedWriteCapacityUnits`.

I want to extend that alarm creator module to also create alarms for the indexes of the table, for such I need to read the secondary indexes (more concretely a global one) to check if the table has any; and if it does then create the alarms. Those alarms should be over capacity consumption and throttled requests (but might be extended to other metrics).

1. Given a table cdk object, how can I list the secondary indexes it has?
2. Having retrieved the secondary indexes, how can I now if they are local or global?
3. Having retrieved a global secondary index, how can I get the metrics associated with it; capacity usage and throttled requests?

Answer (score 1):

> Given a table cdk object, how can I list the secondary indexes it has?

This is the tricky bit. The indexes are not available on the [`ITable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.ITable.html), only the [`CfnTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.CfnTable.html#globalsecondaryindexes). Getting from the `ITable` to the `CfnTable` can be done through `table.node.defaultChild`. Then the variables with the indexes have to be resolved in the CDK stack.

> Having retrieved the secondary indexes, how can I [know] if they are local or global?

This is the easy bit. The indexes are in separate variables, `globalSecondaryIndexes` and `localSecondaryIndexes`.

> Having retrieved a global secondary index, how can I get the metrics associated with it; capacity usage and throttled requests?

By passing `{ GlobalSecondaryIndexName: <indexName> }` to the `dimensions` parameter of the metric call.

Below is a class, based on something I just built for work, that does all of the above. It compiles and should even run (not 100% sure it will run because I removed some intermediate scaffolding from our solution and haven't tested this exact code).

```
import * as cloudwatch from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch';
import * as dynamo from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';
import { Construct, Duration } from '@aws-cdk/core';

export class DynamoMonitor extends Construct {

  private static getIndexNames(dynamoTable: dynamo.ITable) {
    // pull the names of any indexes on the current table from construct
    const table = dynamoTable.node.defaultChild as dynamo.CfnTable;
    const indexes = dynamoTable.stack.resolve(table.globalSecondaryIndexes) as
        Array<dynamo.CfnTable.GlobalSecondaryIndexProperty> | undefined;
    const indexNames: string[] = [];
    if (indexes) {
      for (const index of indexes) {
        indexNames.push(index.indexName);
      }
    }
    return indexNames;
  }

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, dynamoTable: dynamo.ITable) {
    super(scope, id);

    const period = Duration.seconds(30);
    const threshold = 50;
    const evaluationPeriods = 5;

    const indexNames = DynamoMonitor.getIndexNames(dynamoTable);
    for (const indexName of indexNames) {
      const throttleEvents = dynamoTable.metric('WriteThrottleEvents', {
        period: period,
        dimensions: { GlobalSecondaryIndexName: indexName },
        statistic: cloudwatch.Statistic.SAMPLE_COUNT,
        unit: cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
      });

      const consumedWriteCapacityUnits = dynamoTable.metricConsumedWriteCapacityUnits({
        label: 'ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits',
        dimensions: { GlobalSecondaryIndexName: indexName },
        period: period,
        statistic: cloudwatch.Statistic.SAMPLE_COUNT,
        unit: cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
      });

      const throttleRate = new cloudwatch.MathExpression({
        expression: '(throttleEvents/consumedWriteCapacityUnits) * 100',
        label: 'WriteThrottleRate',
        usingMetrics: {
          throttleEvents: throttleEvents,
          consumedWriteCapacityUnits: consumedWriteCapacityUnits,
        },
      });

      throttleRate.createAlarm(this, `WriteIndex${indexName}ThrottleRateAlarm`, {
        threshold: threshold,
        evaluationPeriods: evaluationPeriods,
        comparisonOperator: cloudwatch.ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
        alarmDescription: 'this.description',
        treatMissingData: cloudwatch.TreatMissingData.NOT_BREACHING,
      });
    }
  }
}
```